Getting logs from Application insights
I've recently connected Application Insights to my Azure functions application. I write logs using a pattern suggested by Microsoft documentation:
public MyClass {

  private readonly ILogger _logger;

  public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger){
    _logger = logger;
  }
  
  public void MyMethod {
    _loger.LogWarning("Test message");
  }
}

What I do not understand is how to find the test message in Application insights opened in Portal. I'd like to know how to search for messages from "MyClass" with particular error level. Screenshots will be appreciated! Thank you in advance for some help in this newbie question.

They are available in AI > Transaction Search. You need to search for the keyword there like "Test message", basically it's a raw search you can search any thing.

Unrelated to this particular problem, just to give you a heads up: It's really worthwhile to read all the "logging" advice from microsoft. => Logging in C# and .NET You may not need the high-performance stuff (,yet) but you may want to meticulously follow the "don't"s.

When using the portal you can visually query the logs using the transaction search. Logs written using an ILogger implementation usually ends up in the traces table. In the azure portal you can define filters for the Trace Severity Level and CategoryName like shown below. The CategoryName filter in your case should be set to the value <full namespace>.MyClass and the Trace Severity Level should be Warning

Or you can write this query
traces
| where customDimensions.CategoryName == "Full.Namespace.MyClass"
| where severityLevel == 2

using the Logs as shown here:

